# A single multi-object Kalman filter vs. multiple-single-object Kalman filters (plural)

Tags: c++, opencv, time-complexity, kalman-filter

Gidday cobbers/esteemed colleagues,

With multi-object tracking that implements Kalman prediction/correction the general approach I see suggested in other SO threads is to simply have a vector/array of Kalman filters for each object.

i.e. 'multiple-single-object Kalman filters'

But knowing that if you define your state space matrices correctly, states that are independent of each other will remain so once any (coherent) math is said and done - why don't we just augment the various state and associated matrices/vectors involved in a filter with *all* the object 'data' and use *one* Kalman filter? (yes, there will be lots of zeros in most of the matrices).

Is there any algorithmic complexity advantage either way? My intuition is that using one filter vs. many might reduce overhead?

Maybe is it just easier to manage in terms of human readability in dealing with multiple filters?

Any other reasons?

Thanks

p.s. eventual code will be in openCV/C++

Comment: care to comment on the down-vote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by augmenting you mean combining the states of all objects (both means and covariances) into a single super-state and then using a single filter for prediction/estimation of this super-state, then I am afraid your intuition about it being more efficient is most likely wrong.

You need to consider that KF equations involve operations such as matrix inversion, with O(n^3) (or very close to this figure) computational complexity where n is the dimension of the matrix. If you aggregate multiple objects into a single state, the computational complexity will skyrocket, even if there are mostly zeroes as you said.

Dealing with multiple filters, one per tracked object, is in my opinion both cleaner from the design standpoint and a more efficient approach. If you are indeed bottlenecked by KF performance (profile first), consider allocating the Kalman Filter data in a contiguous array to minimize cache misses.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was getting at - your response is interesting to hear - I'm coming from Matlab where I know (at least 'heard' >rolleyes<) that matrix inversions were done cleverly, as in checks for things like zeros were done so as to inform a choice of the optimal algorithm (maybe still keeping O(n^3) but at least greatly reducing 'n')  for every case (well, 'every case' for large enough dimensions). Not the same for openCV ?  I agree it's easier to manage multiple filters, and I would have tried it and tested, but as it would be harder to manage, well, it'd be hard to manage :)

Comment: Also, I only *inferred* it might have better efficiency - that is in the specific case of reducing overhead - which it may still do ?

Comment: I am not so familiar with OpenCV, so I don't really know what kind of optimizations are included in their implementation... As far as the overhead is concerned, you might indeed save some memory for variables which would be multiplied in each filter, but any such gain would probably be more than negated by enlarged covariance matrix which is kept in the filter state in typical implementations (unless it uses some sort of sparse storage).

Comment: Just an update - ended up implementing 'many' kalman filters as it was easier to factor into the class structure as it stands, I wrote them directly (as opposed to openCV's own filter) but still using the openCV 'mat' which copies Matlab syntax for the most part. I'll update again, if ever I get a chance to compare approaches, Matlab vs. openCV might be interesting ...